# How to tell whether a tcplistener is closed?

Tags: go

In Golang, i can `close` a `TCPListener`, however, i can not tell whether a `TCPListener` is closed or not. This info could be used to do some other logic in program.

Comment: If you are the one that closed it, don't you know if it's closed? You can read from it and check the error if you really want to.

Comment: @JimB, i see it. However, what i mean is that whether there is a already exist flag function in `golang` like `Closed()` to check.

Comment: Presumably, if you need to know if the listener is closed, it's because you want to call `Accept` -- in that case just call accept and see if there's an error (since there could be other error conditions). If you're not checking in order to call `Accept`, it's for of some other logic in your program which should be handled separately, and not coupled to the listener.

Answer (score 0):

You could dial to the socket before using it:

```
_, err = net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8021")    //8021 is a closed socket
if err != nil {
    panic("Error, socket not opened")
}
```

**EDIT:**
Maybe this way is more clear:

```
isOpen := true
_, err = net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8021")    //8021 is a closed socket
if err != nil {
    isOpen = false
}

if isOpen {
    //Your logic here
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid that I don't understand your comment. The snippet I post in Go will simply try to open a socket to the specified host and port. err will be nil if that tcp host and port is open and will throw an error if it's closed or doesn't exists. I have edit the answer